# List of array with different keys in a unique array Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, loops

I am iterating data from a JSON file that I previousy fetch with the following code:

```
    getData().then(data => {
                for (const key in data) {
                    if (data.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                       //  do something with the data
                    }
                }
            }
```

The json file is very long, but it look something like this:

```
{ 
  "01": {
     "id" : "01",
     "title" : "example1",
     "size" : "100",
     "pictures" : []
  },
  "02": {
     "id" : "02",
     "title" : "example2",
     "size" : "0",
     "pictures" : []
  },
  "03": {
     "id" : "03",
     "title" : "example3",
     "size" : "300",
     "pictures" : [
       { "pic_name1" : "example_pic1", "source" : "http://example.pic/1234" },
       { "pic_name2" : "example_pic2", "source" : "http://example.pic/4321" },
     ]
  },
  
}
```

Now, to create a function that will filter through my data I need to put all of the size in a separate array (that I will later work with) and I tried this (inside the IF condition)

```
let sizes = new Array(data[key].size);
```

What I need to return is an array, but I get instead a list of array for each size:
["100"]["0"]["300"]...

How do I return a single array with all sizes as a list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply map over each value and *pluck* the size. E.g.

```js
const data = {
    "01": {
        "id" : "01",
        "title" : "example1",
        "size" : "100",
        "pictures" : []
    },
    "02": {
        "id" : "02",
        "title" : "example2",
        "size" : "0",
        "pictures" : []
    },
    "03": {
        "id" : "03",
        "title" : "example3",
        "size" : "300",
        "pictures" : [
            { "pic_name1" : "example_pic1", "source" : "http://example.pic/1234" },
            { "pic_name2" : "example_pic2", "source" : "http://example.pic/4321" },
        ]
    },
};

const sizes = Object.values(data).map(({size}) => size);

console.log(sizes);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [ES8](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/es6/es8_newfeatures.htm) new features inside the if condition,

```
let sizes = Object.values(data).map(({size}) => size);
```